# Force file download inside a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, file, csv

I'm having trouble to make a .csv file and force its download inside a wordpress plugin.

If i call this code inside the php plugin i get "cannot modify headers", and i call i from outside wordpress, i can download the .csv but can't include the wpdb.php (propably because i don't have access outside my plugin folder)

```
<?php
$fileName = 'somefile.csv'; 

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");

$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT nome, email FROM {$wpdb->prefix}coming_soon_lista_email";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
$headerDisplayed = false;

foreach ( $results as $data ) {
    if ( !$headerDisplayed ) {
        fputcsv($fh, array_keys($data));
        $headerDisplayed = true;
    }
    fputcsv($fh, $data);
}
fclose($fh);
exit;
?>
```

What would be the better approach for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
<?php

ob_start();
ob_clean();

$fileName = 'somefile.csv'; 

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");

$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT nome, email FROM {$wpdb->prefix}coming_soon_lista_email";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
$headerDisplayed = false;

foreach ( unserialize($_GET['asd']) as $data ) {
    if ( !$headerDisplayed ) {
        fputcsv($fh, array_keys($data));
        $headerDisplayed = true;
    }
    fputcsv($fh, $data);
}
fclose($fh);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: it didn't work =( `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wp-admin\menu-header.php:107`

Comment: than remove `ob_start();` from this file and add `ob_start();` into your `wp-config.php` file...

Comment: I should not edit the wp-config, as it's going to be used for more than one wordpress copy...

Comment: Don't worry...
There is no other effect of `ob_start()`...just need to start if you use `ob_clean();`
In last week, i also have same problem and i solve with this...

Comment: Nevermind, miss click on save here.

Now it download, but it appends the whole html to the .csv, and none of the strings it should

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when building my [Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-website-data/). I solved it by having an if statement in my plugin's constructor that would interrupt and output the csv.

**This is what I did for mine**

```
function __construct( ){
    if($_GET['export'] == true && $_GET['page'] == 'cwd-management' && is_admin())
    {
        $csv = '';
        foreach ($this->getAll() as $row) { // getAll() just returns all data in a custom table
            $csv .=  $row->ref . "," . $row->data . "\n";
        }

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"cwd-export_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".csv\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        echo $csv;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Without knowing your table structure I cant give a full example  but hopefully you can use my code to add to your plugin class. Then just provide a link that meets the if statment